# Remove repeated occurences in column 2

Tags: awk

I have the following input file with 2 fields separated by tab. I hope to explain good enough.

**Description**

- The field 2 contains chapters. In this case there are 2, `HISTORY OF THE COUNTRY` and `PHYSICAL GEOGRAPHY`,
- All chapters are related with value `10` in field 1.
- The sections beneath each chapter are related with value `07`.
- The content is related with value `05`
- The next chapter begins when $1==10 and $2 different than previous chapter.

  - In this case Chapter 1 goes from line 1 to line 16
  - In this case Chapter 2 goes from line 17 to end of file.
- The chapters, sections and content could appear repeated times in field 2.

**For example:**

HISTORY OF THE COUNTRY appears 4 times between line 1 and line 16

PHYSICAL GEOGRAPHY     appears 2 times between line 17 and end of file

**My goal is:**

Remove repeated occurrences of `Chapters` and `Sections` leaving all in the same order of appearence. For the content, don´t remove anything. I mean,

- for chapter 1, remove repeated `HISTORY OF THE COUNTRY` within
  chapter 1's context (between line 1 and 16)
- for chapter 2, remove repeated `PHYSICAL GEOGRAPHY` within chapter 2's context (between
  line 17 and 25)

**The Input is this:**

```
10  HISTORY OF THE COUNTRY 
07  FIRST   PART    
07  INTRODUCTION    
05  Article   1    
10  HISTORY OF THE COUNTRY 
07  FIRST   PART    
07  INTRODUCTION    
05  Article   2    
10  HISTORY OF THE COUNTRY 
07  SECOND   PART   
07  REVIEW          
05  Article   1    
10  HISTORY OF THE COUNTRY 
07  SECOND   PART   
07  METHODOLOGY     
05  Article1       
10  PHYSICAL GEOGRAPHY
07  FIRST   PART    
07  INTRODUCTION    
05  First   section 
10  PHYSICAL GEOGRAPHY
07  FIRST   PART    
07  INTRODUCTION    
05  Second   Section
```

**and output would be like this:**

```
10  HISTORY OF THE COUNTRY
07  FIRST   PART    
07  INTRODUCTION    
05  Article   1    
05  Article   2    
07  SECOND   PART   
07  REVIEW          
05  Article   1    
07  METHODOLOGY     
05  Article1       
10  PHYSICAL GEOGRAPHY
07  FIRST   PART    
07  INTRODUCTION    
05  First   section 
05  Second   Section
```

My current code prints something close, but not what I'm looking for.

```
awk '$2 in a {next} {
    a[$2]++
}1' input.txt

10  HISTORY OF THE COUNTRY
07  FIRST   PART
07  INTRODUCTION
05  Article   1
07  SECOND   PART
07  REVIEW
07  METHODOLOGY
05  Article1
10  PHYSICAL GEOGRAPHY
05  First   section
05  Second   Section
```

To ease understanding, I show below the input with chapters in yellow and orange, sections in green. Besides that I show current output and desired output. Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another `awk`

You need to apply uniqueness in a path dependent way.  Print all unique chapters, parts within a chapter, and articles/sections within a part.

```
$ awk '$1=="10" && !h1[c=$0]++; 
       $1=="07" && !h2[c,s=$0]++; 
       $1=="05" && !h3[c,s,$0]++' file

10  HISTORY OF THE COUNTRY
07  FIRST   PART
07  INTRODUCTION
05  Article   1
05  Article   2
07  SECOND   PART
07  REVIEW
05  Article   1
07  METHODOLOGY
05  Article1
10  PHYSICAL GEOGRAPHY
07  FIRST   PART
07  INTRODUCTION
05  First   section
05  Second   Section
```

`{print $0}` is implied when the statement is missing.

in `awk` associated array `a[k]` (similar to hash maps) using the key k, initially equal to `0` or null value (false in boolean), post incremented `a[k]++` and negated `!a[k]++`.  So it will only be true for the first `k`, therefore can be used as a unique filter.  Here `h1, h2, and h3` correspond to unique headers at each level, where keys include the parent path as well, will only print the unique values based on the keys.

This script can be shortened for this problem but as given it's easy to modify if you need to add another layer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  What does this parts  `!h3[c,s,$0]++`? And how is printing the result even you don't have print command in your script?

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -F '\t' '$1 == 10 { ch = $2; sec = "" } $1+0 == 7 { sec = $2 }
             ($1+0 == 5 && !seen[ch,sec,$0]++) || !seen[ch,$0]++' file
```

```
10  HISTORY OF THE COUNTRY
07  FIRST   PART
07  INTRODUCTION
05  Article   1
05  Article   2
07  SECOND   PART
07  REVIEW
05  Article   1
07  METHODOLOGY
05  Article1
10  PHYSICAL GEOGRAPHY
07  FIRST   PART
07  INTRODUCTION
05  First   section
05  Second   Section
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Trying to understand your logic. Why you use `$1 + 0`?

Comment: that's to convert `07` string to the number `7`.  Alternative is writing `$1=="07"` which is one char longer.

Comment: @karakfa thanks for your answer about $1+0. How can I insert a print statement inside your solution, in order to show what is going on after awk reads each line?. To understand better what happens and what do the arrays like this `!h3[c,s,$0]++`

Comment: You can ad `print` like this: `($1+0 == 5 && !seen[ch,sec,$0]++) || !seen[ch,$0]++{print [ch,sec,$0], [ch,$0]}`

Comment: @anubhava thank you for your answer. I tried but I get error when I add `{print [ch,sec,$0]}` at the end of your script `... !seen[ch,$0]++`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to debug, did it not match your expected output?

Comment: I was getting error, but now it works. Thanks so much for the help